# Excel Group rows based on time interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel result:

[image]

I want to group the above result in groups based on sessions i.e. if the time gap between two successive timestamps is greater than 5 minutes, it must be a new row. 
For example :

[image]

I need some formula to achieve this. As I'm fairly new to Excel this is causing to be a major headache for me. Please help me, if anyone knows how to do it or at least point me in a direction.

Thanks a ton !!!

Comment: Can you put the times into your question as text not images plz so that people can copy and paste them to try out any answers they may come up with? Also say what you have tried so far.

Comment: how do you define two successive timestamps (start time and end time from P)?

Comment: Well, can't copy your data but countif() will do this.

Comment: Two successive timestamps would be any time with time interval less than 5 minutes between them. Sorry, I should've mentioned it earlier. Also, if you see the first image, all the time range between 2020-01-07 06:03:16 UTC and 2020-01-07 06:21:03 UTC
 have minute interval less than 5 minutes and hence, will be considered as one group.

Comment: copying and pasting the values from excel will go a long way to getting you an answer.  Don't worry about formatting looking ugly, we can fix that for you most likely.

Comment: lets assume your first time value is in P2.  If you place the following formula in an empty cell on the same sheet, what answer do you get?  `=ISTEXT(P2)`

Comment: Are all counts supposed to equal 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot, it appears your timestamps are actually text values.  Text by default is usually left aligned where as numbers are right aligned.  You seem to have a space at the end of your time stamp suggesting that it is probably left aligned and therefore text.  You can test it with the following formula which will return TRUE if its text.

```
=ISTEXT(P2)
```

where P2 is one of your time stamps.

#### CONVERT TIMESTAMPS TO TIME

There are a variety of ways to do this.  Some will depend on system settings.  Take a look at the following functions as each might be useable depending on your system.  The first two are a guarantee, the last two are more dependent on system settings.

- DATE
- TIME
- DATEVALUE
- TIMEVALUE

Something important to remember here is that in excel dates are integers counting the days since 1900/01/01 with that date being 1.  Time is stored as a decimal and represents fraction/percentage of a day.  24:00:00 is not a valid time in excel though some functions may work with it.

So in order to convert your time stamp in P2 I used the following formula to pull out the date:

```
=DATE(LEFT(P2,4),MID(P2,FIND("-",P2)+1,2),MID(P2,FIND(" ",P2)-2,2))
```

Basically it goes into the text and strips out the individual numbers for Year, Month and Day.

To pull out the time, I could have done the same procedure but elected to demonstrate the TIMEVALUE method which is a little more robust than DATEVALUE and not a subjective to system settings as much.  With the following formula I stripped out the whole time code (MINUS"UTC"):

```
=TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(P2,FIND(" ",P2)+1,FIND("UTC",P2)-FIND(" ",P2)-1)))
```

I also made an assumption that you are not mixing and matching UTC with other time zones which means it can be ignored.  Now to get DATE and TIME all in one cell, you just need to add the two formulas together to get:

```
=DATE(LEFT(P2,4),MID(P2,FIND("-",P2)+1,2),MID(P2,FIND(" ",P2)-2,2))+TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(P2,FIND(" ",P2)+1,FIND("UTC",P2)-FIND(" ",P2)-1)))
```

In the example at the end, I placed that formula in Q2 and copied down

#### DELTA TIME

Since you want to break your groups out based on a time difference between individual entries, I used a helper column to store the time difference. In my example at the end I stored this difference in Column S.  The first entry is blank as there is no time before it.  I used the following formula in S3 and copied it downward.

```
=Q3-Q2
```

I applied the custom formatting of [h]:mm:ss to the cell to get it to display as shown.

#### FIND GROUP BREAK POINTS

In my example I am using helper column T to hold breakpoint flags.  At a minimum, you will have two break points.  Your first time entry and your last time entry.  To make like simple I simply hard coded my first breakpoint flag in T2 as 1.  Stating in T3, Three checks need to be made.  If any of them are TRUE then the next flag needs to be added with a value increase by one.  the three checks are:

- Is this the last entry
- Is the next time delta greater than 5 minutes (means end of a group)
- Is this time delta greater than 5 minutes (means start of a group)

Based on those three checks I placed the following formula in T3 and copied down:

```
=IF(OR(S4="",S4>TIME(0,5,0),S3>TIME(0,5,0)),MAX($T$2:T2)+1,"")
```

Note the $ on the first part of the range for the MAX function.  This will lock the start of the range while the formula gets copied down while the end of the range increases accordingly.

Also the row after the last time entry must be blank. IF it is not blank and has a set value in it, change the S4="" to S4="set value".

#### GENERATE TABLE

There are multiple ways to reference the flags and pull the corresponding times.  a couple of formulas you can look into are:

- INDEX / MATCH
- LOOKUP

In this example I elected to use LOOKUP though I believe INDEX and MATCH are more appropriate and robust.  For starters we want to generate a list of ODD number and EVEN numbers.  These represent the start and end of the groups and correspond to the flags set in column T.  One way to generate ODD and EVEN numbers as you copy down is:

```
=ROW(A1)*2-1  (ODD)
=ROW(A1)*2    (EVEN)
```

The next step is to find the generated number in Column T and then pull its corresponding timestamp in Column Q.  I did this with the following formula in V2 and copied down.

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(A1)*2-1,T:T,Q:Q)
```

And in W2

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(A1)*2,T:T,Q:Q)
```

[image: POC]

Comment: Thanks a ton man. I used parts of your above answer to attain my goal. Thanks again !!!